What should I do when following up a job offer after not hearing back for a while?
Bit of a long one. I have been undertaking multiple interviews with different companies in hopes of securing a graduate/junior role and as of last week I was told by a big company in London that they wished to have me on board as part of their team. They told me in my interview on Wednesday that the next steps would be a matter of negotiating a package that we both deem acceptable and hopefully I join them as part of their department. On Thursday I had an interview feedback meeting with their hiring manager where he confirmed that I had indeed been offered the job and wanted to know what my next steps were. It was in this meeting where I had been told about the salary, as prior to this it was undisclosed. I asked for the offer to be sent to my email in writing and continued some final stage interviews that I had that same week, but discontinued first stage interviews that had recently been arranged.
On Friday morning, another company expressed interest in having me on board with their team for a slightly higher salary outside of London. I decided to take this to the hiring manager on Friday afternoon and sent off a salary negotiation email asking what could be done on their part when factoring in industry standards, the cost of living, and my experience/qualifications in relevance to the role. I believe that the email was well-written and put the ball in their court without any added pressure. I prefer the London company so wanted to see what could be done as negotiating was brought up in my final stage interview as something that was available to me. Fast forward to today, and I have heard absolutely nothing back from them, though the hiring manager did look at my LinkedIn profile a couple of hours after I sent my negotiation email on Friday which I assume means that my email was acknowledged. I factored in the bank holiday weekend and decided to give them 3 business days following my email before I would send a friendly reminder email asking for any updates. As of yet, I've still heard nothing back from the company.
I'm very new to the corporate/professional workplace. I was just wondering what the standard response time is when dealing with big companies and salary negotiations? Is it a bad thing that I've heard nothing a week after receiving my offer from the company despite trying to communicate with them twice now? I'm somewhat of an anxious person so it's hard to tell when I should be genuinely concerned or when its just a matter of patience. The other company outside of London has given me time to make my decision and wants to meet with me in person next week. Any advice on what to expect/how to proceed would be very much appreciated.

I am confused.  Today is Thursday, yesterday was Wednesday, and tomorrow was Friday, and you are worried that you have not heard a response within what timeframe exactly? According to the back of the napkin math, your interview was yesterday and today is I also thought the holiday weekend was last weekend.

You said you received an offer. The offer letter usually states 'Start Day'. do you have it spelled out for you? There should be salary stated in there as well. If so, then you are all set. If you received a 'verbal offer' with unknown salary $$ then it is like chasing a pie in the sky... Do not dwell on those things, just keep looking for work, keep interviewing until a written offer comes in.
Do research on Glassdoor to get an idea of what your current market value is. when negotiating ask them about budgeted range for the role. You will then know if they are worthy of your time.
Following up once a week is acceptable. It lets them know that you are still in the picture and are still interested.


I believe that the email was well-written and put the ball in their
court without any added pressure.

Whenever you propose a negotiation, you risk that they end the conversation. They can tell you nicely, they can tell you rudely, or they can just not respond. Or they can continue the conversation.

I was just wondering what the standard response time is when dealing
with big companies and salary negotiations?

There is no standard.

I prefer the London company so wanted to see what could be done as
negotiating was brought up in my final stage interview as something
that was available to me.

When you negotiate with the one that you prefer, you risk having to settle for the one you don't prefer.
